# Unexpected height while using flexbox model

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a side menu and i  want to use flexbox model. But i have a problem that i haven't solved.

In my menu there are some list element (like dashboard, componenets, ...). This list elements are in `<a>` tag. When you look with inspector tool the height of `<a>` tag is normal but containing `<li>` tags height is strangely long. There is some padding in `<li>` but not that much. There is no reaseon for the `<li>` is long like this.

The reason that i use flexbox model in `<a>` is there is some other element is `<a>` to be positioned in my original project. But i didn't put them in this example.

The height of `<a>`: https://postimg.org/image/7cqo2pazf/

The height of `<li>`: https://postimg.org/image/kgw8feaqz/

Why do you think this strangely long height of `<li>` is happened?

```css
.left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li {
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li>a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #111;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Components</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Forms</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Tables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you want use flexbox in this case?

Comment: there is no need to use flex for `a` .. maybe you want to use flex on `li`... by the way if you want to use flex for a, simply add flex to li and the issue will be fixed

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I have explained it in my question. There are some other elements in`a`. So i use flex to position these elements. But why i have to use a second flex for `li` ?

Comment: @Gaslan i understand, but there is no logic to put other element inside `a` tag. Maybe you need to have submenu, so they will go inside the `li` not the `a`

Comment: @TemaniAfif, there is menu icon in the left and an arrow icon in the right and in the middle label. I want to position these 3 element with flexbox

Comment: `there is menu icon in the left and an arrow icon in the right and in the middle label` and why flex for this ? all of them are inline item. and then you will have text, so you have to put it inside span if you want to use flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add display:block to your list.

```
.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li {
padding: 2px 8px;
display: block;
}
```

Have a look at this snippet

```css
.left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  display:block;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li>a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #111;
}

.left-menu .menu-container>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Components</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Forms</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Tables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue but ididn't understand why i have to give `display:block` to the `li`

Comment: Am not sure with the issue but happen because of display:flex property of <a> tag inside display:list-item of <li> tag. So adding block level display that is display:block cannot make room for xtra to child elements it blocks the region with the parent what you give to child. So am added display:block to list that is parent of <a> and <ul> has already default display value to display:block.